# Swift Map kit annotation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, annotations

I have the following code, but it doesn´t show the location.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit    
import MapKit    
import CoreLocation

class ViewTwo : UIViewController {

 @IBOutlet var Map: MKMapView!

 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.385493, 6.741528)
    var span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.2, 0.2)
    var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location , span: span)
    Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    var annotation =  MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = "hi"
    annotation.coordinate = location
    Map.addAnnotation(annotation)
 }
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You are working your code in didReceiveMemoryWarning(). Yo should write your code in viewDidLoad() function.

Answer (score 2):

There might be several things here:

1. Move your code out from there to a *view* event such as `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`. I'll show you an example with the first one:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       var location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.385493, 6.741528)
       var span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.2, 0.2)
       var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location , span: span)
       Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
       var annotation =  MKPointAnnotation()
       annotation.coordinate = location
       annotation.title = "hi"
       annotation.coordinate = location
       Map.addAnnotation(annotation)
   }
   ```
2. Careful if you want to access user location, in that case you **MUST** request for it via a locationManager and add the proper string into the .plist file
3. Finally, be a good *SO* citizen and grant the points to whoever had given the right answer or at the very least comment if none of them are correct (even this one).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
self.Map.setCamera(camera, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated you are working inside of didReceiveMemoryWarning(), you want to place it in viewDidLoad() so that the code is called when the view is loaded.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit    
import MapKit    
import CoreLocation

class ViewTwo : UIViewController {

 @IBOutlet var Map: MKMapView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  var location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.385493, 6.741528)
  var span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.2, 0.2)
  var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location , span: span)
  Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

  var annotation =  MKPointAnnotation()
  annotation.coordinate = location
  annotation.title = "hi"
  annotation.coordinate = location
  Map.addAnnotation(annotation)
 }
```

Comment: Can you please explain in the answer how to work inside the proper method